# Reproducing SAS Factor Analysis in R

Tags: r, factor-analysis, sas, factor-rotation

I need to be able to reproduce some SAS results in R, as far as this is possible (note: I'm very familiar with R and barely used SAS). The original SAS code is as follows:

```
PROC FACTOR CORR DATA=<data> OUT=FactorScore
            SIMPLE
                CORR
                RES
                METHOD=PRINCIPAL
                PRIORS=SMC
            NFACT=10
                MAXITER=100
                HEYWOOD
            SCREE
                ROTATE=PROMAX
                ROUND
                FLAG=.38;

RUN;
```

As far as I'm able to understand, this runs FA with these properties

- PCA-based decomposition (`METHOD=PRINCIPAL`)
- Computing prior communality estimates using squared multiple correlation (`PRIORS=SMC`)
- 10 factors (`NFACT=10`)
- Setting any communality $>1$ to be 1 (`HEYWOOD`)
- Promax rotation (`ROTATE=PROMAX`)
- As no `POWER` is noted, Promax will use default power $k=3$
- While printing the results it drops out loadings smaller than 0.38 (`FLAG=.38`)

The rest of the parameters aren't interesting me (as a matter of fact `FLAG` doesn't either), at least as far as I can understand.

Using R and the same `<data>` file, I want to reproduce the exact same results. Using the `psych` library I've tried `principal(r = data, nfactors = 10, rotate = "promax")` but it's no match, as it has no option equivalent for SAS's `HEYWOOD, MAXITER` params; Another shot was

```
fa(r = data, nfactors = 10, rotate = "promax", SMC = T, max.iter = 100, fm = "pa")
```

which uses the principal decomposition but I still can't specify the `HEYWOOD` correction; In addition, I can't see where I set the power parameter for the promax.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the promax option is supplied lower case. R is case sensitive. Recalculate your output, evaluate it, and edit the question or close it if this works.

Comment: Using `psych` methods you can use either capital or lower case, both are supported. Anyway, changing the case has yielded a bit different results but didn't bring me any closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If appears that fa defaults to iterated principal factors. So, to be somewhat careful in this:
If you want a principal factors solution with priors based on Squared multiple correlations (and not iterated), you code in SAS would be:

```
proc factor n=4 method=prin rotate=none;
priors smc;
var your-variables-here;
run;
```

and the equivalent code in R would be:

```
principalfactors <- fa(YourData, nfactors = HowManyFactorsYouWant, SMC=TRUE,
                       rotate = 'none', fm = 'pa', max.iter=1)
```

(could be that `max.iter=0` is really what you want, but it seems that R doesn't accept that)

For principal factors, you need priors of one, so in SAS:

```
proc factor n=HowManyFactorsYouWant method=prin rotate=none;
priors one;
var your-variables-here;
run;
```

and in R:

```
principalcomponents <- principal(yourdata, nfactors = HowManyFactorsYouWant,
                                 rotate = "none")
```

If you want to iterate these, then in proc Factor, you'd specify `method=prinit`, (and maxiter if you want to increase the iterations) and in fa, you'd leave the defaults or increase them with `max.iter`. Hope this helps.